# Нарушение прав доступа на чтение c++

Tags: c++

Понимаю вопрос заезженный, но ответа в уже заданных вопроса я не нашел.

Есть класс Matrix

```
    class Matrix {
private:
    int rows, cols;
public:
    int **arr;
    int GetRows() { return rows; }
    int GetCols() { return cols; }

private:
    void InitMatrix() {
        arr = new int*[rows];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            arr[i] = new int[cols];
    }
public:
    Matrix(int rows, int cols) {
        this->rows = rows;
        this->cols = cols;
        InitMatrix();
    }
    void RFill(int leftBorder, int rightBorder) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                arr[i][j] = rand() % (rightBorder + 1 - leftBorder) + leftBorder;
    }
    void Add(Matrix sarr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this->rows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < this->cols; j++)
                this->arr[i][j] += sarr.arr[i][j];
    }
    ~Matrix() {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            delete[] arr[i];
        delete[] arr;
        arr = nullptr;
    }
};
```

Вроде выделяется память правильно, но когда происходит удаление возникает ошибка в деструкторе.

> Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x0FB4D9CB (ucrtbased.dll) в MatrixProject.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0xDDDDDDCD.

Метод main

```
Matrix matrix1(3, 3);
matrix1.RFill(10, 20);

Matrix matrix2(3, 3);
matrix2.RFill(10, 20);

matrix1.Add(matrix2);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        cout << matrix1.arr[i][j] << "\t";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить ошибку, и объясните пожалуйста почему она вообще возникает.

Comment: В метод `Add` аргумент передавайте ссылкой на константу и https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: Не реализован конструктор копирования, а сгенерированный компилятором лишь копирует поля, без выделения памяти. Получается, что когда метод Add отработает, то sarr удалится, а это память matrix2, и при удалении matrix2 деструктор попытается очистить уже удалённую память. Как уже сказали выше, нужно реализовать rule of three для корректной работы класса

Comment: acade и Raccoon спасибо огромное за помощь!